# I couldn't go into work due to anxiety, thinking of quitting after 2 weeks

Tags: job-change, quitting, anxiety, mental-health

I started a new job 2 weeks ago in a recruitment company, I took less money and more hours with the hope of getting more progression and commission over time. However, since the day I stared I've been overwhelmed. Every day that I'm at work I feel sick and when someone talks to me I just want to cry. I don't enjoy the role. I don't think it's for me in the slightest. It's unethical and generally doesn't fit my personality. I used to love my previous job but I did have reasons for leaving, their staff turnover was ridiculously high and the manager was hard among other things but it did not make me feel like this.

Yesterday I got to work and the closer I got the more I started crying until I parked my car and had a panic attack, I called my boss to inform him that I wasn't feeling well and that I'd got to work but need to go home. He said thank you for letting him know and 5 mins later he called me back asking questions about whether I'm enjoying the job, I was so panicky I couldn't breathe and I told him I was finding it extremely hard and felt the pressure since day 1. He said it may not be the career for me and told me to take yesterday and today off to have a think. Yesterday I visited the doctor and was told I had anxiety and given Lorazepam medication but I'm not in a situation I feel is impossible to get out of. I spoke to an ex colleague about my previous work place and she said that they are still looking to fill my position and that she will speak to the new manager tomorrow (there has been a new manager since I left) My options are;

1) call my boss tomorrow and tell him I quit and hope I can get my old job back (I don't think going back is an option as it makes me feel physically sick and he told me I'd need to go back with me 100% effort which I can't do) and risk having no job

2) go back and put myself through hell trying to stop myself crying and having another panic attack

3) request a note from my doctor getting me out of work for 2 weeks due to my anxiety to give me time to think

I cannot decide what to do. I know it's hard to get another job when unemployed but I feel I can't go back: when I think about it I go into panic mode. I have until tomorrow to decide and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow it seems like you are truly living a nightmare at your job...Are those "unethical" tasks you're performing legal ?

Comment: Just get out of there! Try and get another job first, but if you can't stick it out ( and don't feel bad if you can't) just leave.

Comment: You say you found this job through a recruitment agency.  Why not ask them if they have anything else available that needs similar skills?

Comment: I didn't find my job through a recruitment agency I work for a recruitment agency, the tasks I'm doing are legal but go against my morals. It's a very tough job I feel I've given it a go but I just don't want to stay. Won't it look awful if I'm looking for a new job unemployed?

Comment: @Sperkins: it won't look awful, but usually being unemployed makes it more difficult to find a new job. However, in your particular case, it will be probably easier to find something new being unemployed but having your anxiety under control than employed while having this level of anxiety.

Answer (score 7):

If i was feeling like that I would quit, without a doubt. You need a change, and TRUST ME, you don't want to underestimate your own mental health. Stress, depression all seems within reach for you, if you are not careful.

> Every day that I'm at work I feel sick and when someone talks to me I just want to cry

I have had my share amount of days like that - my mistake was not quitting in time.

Remember to put yourself first - no one else is gonna do that for you.

Whatever job you want to pursue is up to you, and your gut - but I have no doubt you need to get out of current position. Maybe go back and rethink what you really want to pursue as a career.

Stay positive - everything is gonna be okay.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever is your job, if you feel **this** bad, you're doing the best choice by going elsewhere.

Normally the best thing to do is to stay at your job, update your resume and start answering to offers. Once an offer is confirmed via a contract you tell your company you're quitting.

But your situation is really different, since your job makes you physically ill. In this case, if you really can't stand your job anymore, you should tell your boss you can't take it anymore and want to quit. Again, in another situation I would have told you "talk about it with your boss and try to figure out how to improve your job", but the fact that you told him everything about how you feel and his reaction was "take 2 days off and think about it" makes me think the situation is not going to improve at your current company any time soon.

If you really can't go, just don't. It's your health, it's more important than your job. If your boss can't understand that, then quitting even before having an offer on the table seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, you're personal health is the top priority even if it means staying unemployed for a while. You couldn't work as 100% of your capacity if you are mentally and physically on the edges of crisis, none of us can and your boss doesn't seems to get it.

In that situation, I would take option three and go to the doctor to request a note that would keep me far away from work for a while. I would then use this time to update my resume and start to seek actively for a new job.

I don't think that getting back to your previous job will help forgetting the nightmare you're living in you're current one. You need changes, and a new fresh start.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice, but if I did quit, how would I explain this in an interview going forward? Should I put the new place on my Cv even though I had only worked there 2 weeks. How do I go about explaining it? Has anyone done agency work? I just feel lost